# Do we need encrypt session id before saving it into database

Tags: security, session, encryption

I want to use database as session storage. I design a simple table containing 3 columns:
SessionID, Key, Value ( Session ID & Key will be primary key).

My question is should I encrypt user Session ID before saving it into the table? In my opinion, I should do it because it prevents someone (who has access database) seeing active session ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could encrypt the session, but it's not standard practice. Typically, the database is well protected, with only the web/application server being able to access it.

Also, since sessions should expire (and time out), the damage is mitigated to a small window of time even if it were accessed.

If you do decide to encrypt the session ID, it should be fairly easy, especially if you have an object oriented approach. You can simply encrypt the session near the persistence layer.

A more common problem is having the session ID sniffed off the wire. Ensure you're forcing HTTPS between the client/browser and application/web server to prevent that.

Also, you can request the password again on any serious operations to further mitigate session hijacking issues.

Comment: Thanks. I like your ideas: HTTPS + request password again on any serious actions.